# when it is conditional entropy minimized?

Tags: conditional-probability, entropy

for example let us consider following table

[image]

know that entropy of variable is maximum when  it is equally distributed,all of it's variable has equal probability,but what  about joint  entropy or conditional entropy?we know that channel capacity is equal

$I(X,Y)=H(X)-H(X|Y)=H(Y)-H(Y|X)$

it is equal maximum when $H(X)$ is maximum  and $H(X|Y)$ is minimum,but when it happens this?for first we can say that all marginal probability of  $X$ should be equal to each other,but what about second?is it same also?clearly if $H(X|Y)$ is zero in addition of $H(X)$ be maximum,then we will have  maximum mutual information,but when it happens?thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$H(X|Y)=\sum_{i,j}p(x,y)\log(p(x|y))$$

So to make this zero we want $p(x|y)=1$ whenever $p(x,y)\neq 0$. This means that $x$ is a function of $y$. So to maximise $I(X,Y)$, take both variables to be equal and with uniform marginals.

Comment: by uniform marginal you mean?