# Zero conditional entropy

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, entropy

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848158/when-it-is-conditional-entropy-minimized) math.se question but I need a bit more guidance.

For two discrete random variables $X,Y$ we define their  conditional entropy to be $$H(X|Y) = -\sum_{y \in Y} Pr[Y = y] ( \sum_{x \in X} Pr[X = x | Y = y] \log_2{Pr[X=x|Y=y]}).$$

I would like to show that $H(X|Y) = 0$ if and only if $X = f(Y)$ for some function $Y.$

Can someone help me with this? I don't know how the fact that $X,Y$ are related by a function implies $H(X|Y) = 0$ and vice versa.

Comment: Hint: Since every term is nonpositive, for every y such that Pr[Y = y]>0 you want that Pr[X = x | Y = y].log_2Pr[X=x|Y=y]=0 for every x. When is this possible? You might want to first solve t.log_2(t)=0 for t.

Comment: @Did The condition Pr [Y = y] > 0 implies $Pr [X = x | Y = y] \in \{0,1\}$ for every $x.$ How does it then imply that $X$ is a function of $Y?$

Comment: For each y, select the unique x such that Pr[X=x|Y=y]=1 and call it x=u(y). What do you think of the random variable u(Y)?

Comment: @Did Thanks. That helped! If you care to put this in an answer I am glad to accept it.

Comment: Better idea: you write down a solution and post it as an answer here. After a while, you might even "accept" it (cool, eh?).

Comment: @Did can you put the answer then (it has been a lot of time with this question unanswered)? Thanks!

Comment: @user886869 No. You are welcome. But please do that yourself if you fancy it.

Comment: Ok, @Did I don't know how to formulate the answer yet (working on my way to it), but thanks anyway.